# How to construct a table of changes using data.table in R?

Tags: r, data.table

Given the following data:

```
library(data.table)

demo <- data.table(ID = c("A", "A", "A", "A","A", "B", "B","B", "C","C","C", "D",
                  "D"),
           Year = c(2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 
                    2012, 2013, 2015,
                    2013, 2014, 2015,
                    2013, 2015))
```

We can clearly see that for the ID of A, it does not seem to change over time and therefore no changes should be registered.
But for the ID of B, we see a change in 2011 to 2012, 2013 to 2014 and 2014 to 2015 and we would like to show these changes.

A clear picture of this data is shown below.

[image: Table of the data]

Now, to construct this in R, I can actually do the following:

```
demo[, Value := 1]
dcast(demo, ID ~ Year, value.var = "Value", fill = 0)
```

And then try to manually calculate the changes between each year. The resulting table would then be like the red table below.

[image: Result]

However, if there are many years, a programmatic solution would be more efficient and cleaner. I wonder whether something like that is possible (without a for-loop).

Answer (score 2):

You should always work in long format with data.table.

```
demo[, val := 1]
#add missing years for IDs:
demo <- demo[CJ(ID = unique(ID), Year = unique(Year)), on = .(ID, Year)]
demo[is.na(val), val := 0L]
#calculate differences:
demo <- demo[, .(Years = paste(head(Year, -1), tail(Year, -1), sep = "-"),
         Diff = diff(val)), by = ID]
dcast(demo, ID ~ Years)
#   ID 2011-2012 2012-2013 2013-2014 2014-2015
#1:  A         0         0         0         0
#2:  B         1         0        -1         1
#3:  C         0         1         0         0
#4:  D         0         1        -1         1
```

Answer (score 0):

We are pretty there to get the desired value. An option could be to change back to `data.frame` and perform matrix operation (`subtraction`) on `demo` in wide format.

```
library(data.table)
demo[, Value := 1]
DT <- dcast(demo, ID ~ Year, value.var = "Value", fill = 0) 
# change back to data.frame to use matrix operation
setDF(DT)

#matrix operation with a column shift
cbind(DT[1], DT[,3:6] - DT[,2:5])
#   ID 2012 2013 2014 2015
# 1  A    0    0    0    0
# 2  B    1    0   -1    1
# 3  C    0    1    0    0
# 4  D    0    1   -1    1
```

**Data:**

```
library(data.table)

demo <- data.table(ID = c("A", "A", "A", "A","A", "B", "B","B", "C","C","C", "D",
                  "D"),
           Year = c(2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 
                    2012, 2013, 2015,
                    2013, 2014, 2015,
                    2013, 2015))
```